# Group Dictionary by splitting the Key and create new Dictionary

Tags: c#, string, linq, dictionary, split

I have a Dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"aa:bb", MyObject1},
    {"aa:cc", MyObject2},
    {"dd:xx", MyObject3},
    {"dd:yy", MyObject4}
};
```

The key of the dictionary is a string with `':'` as delimiter. Now I want do create from that Dictionary a new one:

```
Dictionary<string, object> ddProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
{"xx", MyObject3},
{"yy", MyObject4}
};
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to create the new Dictionary by splitting the key of the original Dictionary. Is that possible with LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var ddProperties = properties.ToDictionary
                    (kvp => kvp.Key.Split(':')[1], kvp => kvp.Value);
```

If you only need the ones beginning with `dd` (as can be seen in your sample output), I would do:

```
var filteredPairs = from kvp in properties
                    let split = kvp.Key.Split(':')
                    where split[0] == "dd"
                    select new { Key = split[1], kvp.Value };

var ddProperties = filteredPairs.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Do note that there is no protection against duplicates here. If you're expecting duplicate keys after transformation, how would you like to handle them?

Comment: Looks like he wants only a subset of the elements, ones where the first half of the key is a specific identifier (`"dd"` in his example), so you'll need a Where clause as well.

Answer (score 1):

note that since each entry is multiple results, use [`.SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

As mentioned, [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.95).aspx) builds dictionaries nicely

```
properties
    .SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Key.Split(':')
         // Select each item in the split
         //  to gain access to the original Key Value Pair parameter
        .Select(key => new { Key = key, Value = kvp.Value }))
    .ToDictionary(
        a => a.Key,
        a => a.Value);
```